Docker image for a python selenium app using headless chrome
I am doing a headless scraping with selenium and trying to create a docker image to deploy my script on cloud run. Below is my dockerfile, when I run it I am getting this error
**"message": "Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.\n  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
**
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.10

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/credentials.json


RUN pip install --no-cache-dir chromedriver-py -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean


CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]

I tried running the container with docker run --shm-size=2g -p 8080:8080, to increase the shared memo size but still same error.
